# How to stop sound classification in ml5.js

Tags: audio, classification, ml5.js

Is it possible to programmatically stop sound classification process? I don't find any method or function to do it.
Ex:

```js
const classifier = ml5.soundClassifier('path/to/model.json', options, modelReadyCallback);
// start classification
classifier.classify(gotResult);
// but how to stop?
classifier.stop(); // no such method
```

Reloading the page can solve the problem, but it is not the required solution.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am doing

```
classifier.model.model.stopListening()
```

For the start

The model includes a "listen" method, however, I have yet to discover the appropriate values for it.

Recreating the classifier seems to be a solution.